# beta-equivalence, beta-reduction and transitive+reflexive beta-reduction

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm taking an intro course in Lambda calculus and I cannot understand why in the following exercise, the first two sentences are false and only the last one is true:

λx.x β
λx.x: False

λx.x -<sup>β</sup> λx.x: False

λx.x --<sup>β</sup> λx.x: True (beta-reduction closed under transitivity and reflexivity)

I thought that in an identity function, there should be no difference between beta-equivalence, beta-reduction and transitive and reflexive beta-reduction